# How can I get the caret position after clicking on selection of input text box?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an input box with text selected inside.

When I click inside the selection area I would like to receive the caret position.

The only attribute I see that might be usefull is the selection start attribute but it is allways 0 due to the selected input box.

How can I receive the click's caret location?

Comment: It is not a duplication because my problem happens after clicking selected text, not on specific types of elements

Comment: so basically you mean: I select a text portion, and than I click inside that selection? (and out of curiosity, what you need it for?)

Comment: yes thats what I meant, I need it as a requirement for a product I am working on, Is there a way to do it in JQuery maybe?

Comment: Have you tried to tweak the code posted in other answers?

Comment: obviously.. so far no luck but i keep trying

Comment: Keep trying and than post here some code of what you have so far - and we'll take a look. A demo on jsBin would be nice tho

Answer (score 0):

You can get caret position inside a text box on click inside it, but as selected text is not a DOM node you can't assign click event on selected portion. If you just want clicked caret position this will help you.

```
    function GetCaretPosition(ctrl) {
        var CaretPos = 0; // IE Support
    if (document.selection) {
            ctrl.focus();
            var Sel = document.selection.createRange();
            Sel.moveStart('character', - ctrl.value.length);
            CaretPos = Sel.text.length;
        }
        // Firefox support
        else if (ctrl.selectionStart || ctrl.selectionStart == '0') CaretPos = ctrl.selectionStart;
        return (CaretPos);
    }

$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('.textBox').click(function(e) {
        alert(GetCaretPosition(this));
    });
});
```

check http://jsfiddle.net/thvd5/